# How to continue resizing partition after unexpected shut down manjaro

Tags: kde-plasma, manjaro, data-loss, disk-partitioning

Good morning everyone, I had a BIG problem. I was resizing a partition of my computer with Manjaro KDE x64 and my PC unexpectedly shut down and I loss my partition table and my data apparently.
[Partition table after shut down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D283L.png)

The last 2 volumes correspond to my past previous partition and I don't know hoy to revert it or continue with the process in order to restore my information.
[KDE partition manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfSvB.png)

This is my system basis information.
[System information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSGae.png)

I did not make a backup of my partition table, I'm an idiot. I'm not gona do anything without the security to know that I'll recover my information.

Thanks for reading my post, I hope to get some help, please let me know if you need more information about anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you where doing shrinking/growing or those operations with moving.

You are in one of these cases

1. When you shrink partition then first filesystem is reduced (on the right edge), then partition table is adjusted to reduce partition size. Unexpected reboot is unlikely to break anything.
2. When you are growing (on the right edge), then partition table is adjusted to increase partition, and then filesystem is increased. Data loss is again unlikely, worse outcome should be filesystem does not span the whole partition, easy to fix.
3. If you are growing partition on the left edge, then first partition is increased, then data is moved to the new left edge of partition and then filesystem is resized. If you reboot while data is being moved, filesystem would be discontinuous, i.e. part of filesystem, gap, remaining filesystem. To recover you would need to identify where the gap is and move remaining part of filesystem, but it's not easy to do that, I don't think there are any tools to identify where gap is (that gap will not be zeroes on the disk, it's some old data).
4. If you are shrinking partition on the left then first file system is reduced, then it is moved to the right, and then partition boundaries are adjusted. Unexpected reboot while data is being moved will also cause a gap in the filesystem like in case 3) with the same problems if you need to recover.

Backup of just old partition table would not have helped much, since the gap in the filesystem depends on the time when reboot happened. Only backup of all data would help.